# Send message to a hwnd in C#

Tags: c++, wpf, mfc, sendmessage

I have a WPF application and a MFC application. I want to do a two communication between them. I can use SendMessage in mfc application to send messages to WPF application. How can I do the same in WPF application?

Comment: Just pinvoke SendMessage().  Do consider a better mousetrap like named pipes or sockets, much easier to find the other end and much easier to use in a WPF app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do it in MFC, then you can do it in C# too by importing the SendMessage API call:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, StringBuilder lParam);
```

You can find sample usage of SendMessage in [this link](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendmessage).